# app crashing due to resource not loading properly randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, crash

basically Im making a game on Sprite Kit using Obj-C in XCode 5
whenever I tap the screen, I use an SKAction to play a sound file

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"tap.caf" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

Previously I used the mp3 file that i had of the same sound and the error kept popping up randomly after about more than 50 taps at least, sometimes more sometimes less, sometimes it doesn't even cause an error,

So i read the apple documentation and decided to convert to ima4 .caf extention.
I'm not sure if its made a difference, It happens much less often. I've got 2 more audio files that are played through SKActions and none of them have yet failed loading.

Any suggestions?

Debug console output below:

```
2014-07-05 16:14:15.716 GoUp[777:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'Failed to Load Resource', reason: 'Resource tap.caf can not be loaded'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x306d7fd3 0x3ae86ccf 0x306d7f15 0x32e09e55 0x32dc2b2d 0xf9331 0x32de69ab 0x32f28651
0x32f236eb 0x32ef88ed 0x32ef6f97 0x306a325b 0x306a272b 0x306a0f1f 0x3060bf0f 0x3060bcf3
0x35510663 0x32f5716d 0xfcd61 0x3b393ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Just to add, I tried to check if the file was faulty by setting a repeatforever waitforcomplete:YES SKAction playing the sound file, (i did wait for it to complete each time otherwise, it may have crashed due to significant number of actions). It ran without problem for at least 5 mins, until i decided to stop the app. Not sure if this confirms the file is not damaged

EDIT 2 : Just tried a different sound file and it happened again with a different file :(

Comment: NVM, I think I've fixed it by setting one SKAction for each sound and calling the pointer to the action, apparently, the file doesn't have to be loaded each time this way. No errors yet after many tries.

Answer (score 1):

I have no explanation about why that "crash" occurs,

but, you can easily solve this problem by declaring and loading your sounds into cash *(**to avoid to load it each time** the sound is played)* as follow:

In the .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKAction *aSound;
```

in the .m
Ignit it on the top:

```
self.aSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"FileName.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
```

En then call it each time you want to play the sound:

```
[self runAction:_aSound];
```

**Also and for some reasons,** 
I advice you to **convert all your Audios files into .Wav**, which is uncompressed *(allowing much more speed from the Processor that hasn't uncompressed the file before to read it)*
It also dodge a lot of exceptions in C picked-up from the Breakpoint of Xcode.